# Order of this differential equation and why?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, notation

$$x y^{(4)} + 2 y'' + (x y')^5 = x^3$$

Could someone please explain how this is a fourth order equation? I would have thought it was a second order equation. Does the $4^{th}$ power on the $y$ make a difference?

Comment: $y^{(4)}$ means $y''''$, it is a shorthand.

Comment: As Moo states, when the superscript is a natural number in parentheses, they almost always mean that derivative. Notice that the $x^3$ is *not* $x^{(3)}$, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$y^{(4)}$ is equal to the $4^{\text{th}}$ derivative of $y$.

So, the order of this equation is $4$.